# Why are non-relative imports not working when I've set baseUrl in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript

I have the following directory structure

```bash
src/
  node_modules
  components/
    MyComponent/
      index.ts
  tsconfig.json
Sites/
  MySite/
    tsconfig.json
    components/
      MyComponent/
       index.ts
```

In `Sites/MySite` the tsconfig contains this

```json
{
  "extends": "../../src/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../../src",
    "rootDirs": ["../../src", "."]
  }
}
```

Imports like `import React from 'react'` are not being found in `Sites/MySite/components/MyComonent/index.ts`. I understood `baseUrl` to be the place at which non-relative imports are resolved from but this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this config

```json
{
  "extends": "../../src/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../../src",
    "rootDirs": ["../../src", "."],
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./node_modules/*",
        "./node_modules/@types/*",
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```